# Spring Autowiring is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

Can someone explain why Autowiring is not working in the following context ?

I have the following class that I would love to Autowire:

```
@Component
public class UserFormatter {
...
}
```

Now I want to Autowire the UserFormatter in this class:
If I declare the UserFormatter as static it works fine but why does it work only this way?

```
@Data
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ScenarioInfo {

    @Transient
    private static UserFormatter userFormatter;

    @Autowired
    public void generateUserFormatter(UserFormatter userFormatter) {
        this.userFormatter = userFormatter;
    }
```

Why can't I just write

```
    @Data
    @Component
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class ScenarioInfo {

        @Transient
        @Autowire
        private UserFormatter userFormatter;
```

And why do I have to use a Function in order to Autowire the userFormatter ?
I'd be happy if someone could help me.:)

Comment: Your first snippet can't possibly compile. Your second one should work fine. Make sure you're not using `new` to create a ScenarioInfo by yourself. Spring can only autowire the beans that it creates. Not the objects you create. Also make sure that it's in a package that is component-scanned. We can only make guesses with the few lines of code you posted. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Why can't it possibly compile because it does and it is successfully Autowired. 
In the second sniped the user Formatter is not Autowired. 
Oh I thought that it only applies to the UserFormatter which should not be created by  myself. What can I do If I want to Autowire as in the second snipped but also be able to create ScenarioInfo objects? Is it only be possible to Autowire as I do it in the first snipped ?

Comment: Oh sorry. It does, but makes no sense. Initializing a static field from a constructor makes no sense. A static field is shared by all instances of a class. A constructor initializes one instance. If you want to create instances of ScenarioInfo by yourself, then it shouldn't be a Spring bean, and thus shouldn't have autowired fields. Just pass the UserFormatter by yourself in the constructor when instantiating one, and remove the Component annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I gonna remove the autowired fields. Thank you for your help ! :)
(But I'm initialize the static field by a function not by a constructor which is autowired.)

Comment: Same thing: the method is an instance method. You're using a method that is specific to an instance to modify a static field that is shared by all instances.

Comment: Also why are you marking the instance field as `@Transient`?

Comment: Because I don't want that the userFormatter is serialized. Right now I'm not sure if it really necessary in this case but I marked it just in case as @Transient

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are initializing your ScenarioInfo class. [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) is right about the use of `new` keyword stopping all the subsequent hierarchical Autowiring. If you want to create the `ScenarioInfo` object straight from the `main` method where `@Autowire` is not possible, then annotate the calling class(which is `App` here) with `@Configuration` and use

`Annotationconfigapplicationcontext ctx = new Annotationconfigapplicationcontext(App.class);
ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo = ctx.getBean(ScenarioInfo.class);`

where the `App` is the class with the `main` method in it. You could also use `BeanFactory` interface and its implementations but `ApplicationContext` is more feature rich. Plus I have never used the BeanFactory` myself, so you'd have to ask someone else  on how to configure it for your project.